# Slingshot - Move / Edit items

Tags: slingshot

I wish there was a way to drag and drop menu items to different categories and right click the items to edit the name/icons. I don't think this has been added yet. Are there any other GUI tools that can do this easily?

I'm looking for an easy way to move an item from one category to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Menulibre 'https://smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/' It's simple GUI to add applications to slingshot and/or change names, icons etc.
It's really easy to use. You can easily change categories, names and descriptions of apps. :)

However, if you want to keep simple. Make a .desktop entry in '/usr/share/applications'. 'https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries'